# jQuery hasClass() function not working after element is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a button that allows the users of my platform to upvote a post or remove the previously cast vote it if the button is pressed again.

The problem is that when the user clicks the button the second time, after the post has been voted nothing happens.

This is the code that manages the button's behavior:

```
if($(".timeline-action-plus").hasClass("btn-success")) {
    $(".timeline-action-plus").click(function(){
        rating.removeVote($(this).data("entry-id"), $(this).data("token"));
    });
} else {
    $(".timeline-action-plus").click(function(){
        rating.votePlus($(this).data("entry-id"), $(this).data("token"));
    });
}
```

The `removeVote` and `votePlus` functions also take care of modifying the button's aspect:

function votePlus(id, token) {

```
    $.post(
        "http://localhost/user/vote",
        {
            rating  : '1',
            entryID : id,
            _token  : token
        },
        function(result) {
            if(result === "OK"){
                $(".timeline-action-plus[data-entry-id=" + id + "]").removeClass("btn-default");
                $(".timeline-action-plus[data-entry-id=" + id + "]").addClass("btn-success");
            }
        }
    );
}

function removeVote(id, token) {
    $.post(
        "http://localhost/user/removeVote",
        {
            entryID : id,
            _token  : token
        },
        function(result) {
            if(result === "OK") {
                $(".timeline-action-plus[data-entry-id=" + id + "]").removeClass("btn-success");
                $(".timeline-action-plus[data-entry-id=" + id + "]").addClass("btn-default");
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Basically the `$(".timeline-action-plus").hasClass("btn-success")` seems to work only before that the button classes are updated by the `removeVote` and `votePlus` functions.

**Edit:**

This is the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs @if(Rating::userHasVoted(Auth::user()->username, $article->id)) btn-success @else btn-default @endif timeline-action timeline-action-plus" data-entry-id="{{$ID}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}" id="vote{{$ID}}" Title="+1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    <span id="voteNumber{{$ID}}"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Do the logic inside the event.

Comment: Keep all your logic/codes inside the handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to move the `hasClass` check inside your click function:

```
$(".timeline-action-plus").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
        rating.removeVote($(this).data("entry-id"), $(this).data("token"));
    else
        rating.votePlus($(this).data("entry-id"), $(this).data("token"));
});
```

This will now perform the check every time the element is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, don't know why I did the other way :)

Comment: @ShadowBroker happy to help! When you get the time could you please mark this as the accepted answer if this has solved your problem. :)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't accept it soon but I had to wait few minutes then i decided to cook something :)